# Erase set iterator value and increment iterator

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have seen a programmer write this.

```
auto it=myset.lower_bound(x);
myset.erase(it++);
```

How can I get the next iterating pointer through post increment operator if I already have deleted the current iterating pointer value?

Comment: `it++` increments the iterator you have, and returns the old value. So you safely update your own copy first, then remove the previous element.

Comment: As this is post increment, so it should erase *it first and increment then.

Comment: I have the same words @logic staff

Comment: @Murad The `it++` happens before the erase.  The function gets the old value of `it` and erases that while the call site holds on to the valid iterator that is the result of `it++`.

Comment: sometimes this code works @NathanOliver.
auto it=myset.lower_bound(x);
myset.erase(it);
cout<<*it;
 //this prints the value of x after deletion process.

Comment: @Murad No, that never works. It might sometimes **appear** to work; that is the nature of Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @Murad That is undefined behavior.  It may or may not work but it is not correct

Comment: Oh thanks to @NathanOliver

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you call

```
myset.erase(it++);
```

A couple things happen.  First `it++` gets evaluated before it is passed to the function.  When you evaluate `it++` the result of that is `it` and that is what gets passed to the function.  So your function gets the value of `it` but the value of `it` in the call site is what it is after being incremented.  That means when `erase` erases the element the iterator points to it is erasing what the old iterator points to that you no longer have.  This is a completely valid and safe way to erase an element from a `set`.

As an alternative, starting in C++11, `erase` returns the next valid iterator so you could use

```
it = myset.erase(it);
```

and it will have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks, I have found this helpful.

Comment: @Murad No problem.  Glad to help

Comment: Maybe add that since C++11 `erase()` returns just this iterator.

Comment: @GillBates Like *As an alternative, starting in C++11, `erase` returns the next valid iterator so you could use `it = myset.erase(it)` and it will have the same effect*?

Comment: Sounds perfect.

Comment: @GillBates Added.

Comment: @PeteBecker Updated the language.

Comment: @NathanOliver It is worth noting also that this pattern is only valid for containers that guarantee only the erased iterator is invalidated, while other iterators are not modified (such as set and list), but it is not a pattern generally applicable (i.e. with a vector this would be UB, as the next iterator would have been invalidated).